# Allow only selected UTF language inputin JavaScript, and validate it server-side

Tags: javascript, php, regex

My page:

```
<option>Hindi हिंदी</option>
<option>Arabic العَرَبِيَّة‎</option>
<option>Kannada ಕನ್ನಡ</option>
<option>Gujarati ગુજરાતી</option>
...
<option>Simplified Chinese 汉语</option>
...
<option>English English</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id='inf' name="info" required>
```

My requirement:

- When I select 'Hindi' language from the select box, in this input type text (id='inf') only Hindi language UTF characters (alphabets and digits) should be accepted, none other. And also should be validated on server side.
  **in the same way**
- When I select 'Arabic' language from the select box, in this input type text (id='inf') only Hindi language UTF characters (alphabets and digits) should be accepted, none other. And also should be validated on server side.

---

Here is one way to achieve this for English language:

**On front end:**

```
<input type="text" id='inf' name="info" onclick="allLetter()" required>
<script>
function allLetter(inputtxt){ 
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
    if(document.getElementById("inf").value.match(letters)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

**On server-side:**

```
if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $string)){
    // string contains only English letters
}
```

But how would you achieve this for languages other than English? I want to achieve this dynamically, without regex blocks for each language.

If one must know the UTF character sets, please give thorough examples with references to UTF.

Comment: Why not provide a regular expression for each of these languages and then run the same matching you already have?

Comment: Exactly as @NicoHaase said. If you had a regular expression set up for each language, then instead of having a block of validation code on the front and back-ends for each, you could simple do something like: `preg_match($regex[$languageSelection], $string)` on the back.